# upload an image as profile photo in iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift

in my iOS app I want to upload an image as a profile photo. So, I need something like an Icon to upload the image and then a popup or such a user interface to make a photo by camera or to upload it from the photo album on device. It should be like Facebook.

I created my app with XCode 6 and Swift. Are there any ideas, solutions or other information?

THX!

Comment: This is a very broad question and not suitable to the format of stackoverflow. Try doing this yourself first, and when you run into some programming issues, then ask another question with some of your code and an explanation of why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem with following code:

```
func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
        var picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        var mediaTypes: Array<AnyObject> = [kUTTypeImage]
        picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        NSLog("No Camera.")
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let selectedImage : UIImage = image
}
```

Comment: Where is kUTTypeImage defined?